# How to change the compared dates in quicksight aws KPI chart

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm building a quicksight dashboard and I want to add a KPI chart that will present the trend (in percentage) of a line chart. The problem is that the KPI only compares the last two dates and the line chart presents the last 6 months.

When I applied a date filter on the KPI it didn't change anything. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible and how?
Thanks a lot!